# Adding images "From SharePoint"

Tags: picture

I'm a novice SharePoint user and am trying to re-build a 2007 SharePoint site in 2010.

Within 2007 I had a number of pictures (jpeg, bmp, gif) stored within the PublishingImages folder on the SharePoint Server. This appeared to allow me to add an image to a Content Editor Web Part from the server as opposed to uploading a new image each time.

I'm trying to replicate this within the SharePoint 2010 i'm currently testing. I've added all the stock images to the Images document library and have been able to add an image to the homepage of the site fine.

I've since created sub-sites and am trying to add images to the Content Editor Web Parts on these sites. I don't seem able to add an image "From SharePoint" as this option is greyed out on the ribbon stating the control is diabled.

All of the sub-sites are inherting the permission from the parent site (homepage) under which i'm an Owner thus have full control.

How to I enable the feature to be able to add images to web parts on the sub-sites from those saved onto the SharePoint Server?

*N.B - i'm re-building the site using Rich Text Editing rather than HTML code given my lack of technical background.*

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the "SharePoint Server Publishing" feature is activated on your subsite.

Site Settings > Site Actions > Manage Site Features > SharePoint Server Publishing : **Activate**

Comment: Hi Phil. Many thanks for your response. Didn't realise i'd have to enable this on each sub-site as well as the homepage. Seems to have resolved my issue :o)